# Jinja2 batch filter - how to get text of various div elements

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

Working with flask & bootstrap 4 I'm using a batch filter to create a new row for every 3 items like so

```
{% for row in teams|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for value,participant in row %}
            <div class="col stackem mb-2">
            <div class="text-center" id="participant">{{ participant }}</div>
            <div class="text-center mb-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal" id ='{{ loop.index }}'>{{ value }}</button></div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then I (am trying) get the participants by id like so

```
participant = document.getElementById("participant").textContent;
```

The problem is that I keep getting only the first participant in the list no matter which div I click on... I tried to reference the loop by making the id similar to the button...

```
id ='{{ loop.index }}'
```

but I still only got 1,2 or 3 as the value because of the batch filter. How can I get the text of the various participants? I'm thinking I have to reference teams (because it contains all participants) but I don't know how to go about getting the index/position for each element in teams due to the batch filter only giving me 1,2 or 3???

Answer (score 1):

Your `participant` ID should be unique. Try this:

```
{% for row in teams|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for value,participant in row %}
            <div class="col stackem mb-2">
            <div class="text-center" id="participant-{{loop.index}}">{{ participant }}</div>
            <div class="text-center mb-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal" id ='{{ loop.index }}'>{{ value }}</button></div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to grab all participants you probably want to use `document.getElementsByClassName` and add `participant` into your class attribute.

Comment: Thanks @afro for feedback. I made the ID unique but am I update the `participant = document.getElementById("participant").textContent;` because now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null for that line...

Comment: There is no `participant` ID now, so you're calling `textContent` on a null object. If you're trying to get the value of `participant` when you click the `button` element, it might be easier for you to attach that data to the button, but I can't tell without more context.